# MQ Manager Connection not participating in transaction scope

Tags: .net, transactions, websphere, ibm-mq

I am working with MQClient 7.5.0.5, with MQ API for .net application.

If I open an MQManager connection using WMQ.MQQueueManager not in a transaction scope,
The connection will not participate in any transaction I open later on.
However, if the connect is done within a transaction scope, the connection will participate in any other transaction scopes later (unrelated to the first transaction scope the connection was opened in).
to explain further:

I have a DoWork method:

```
void DoWork(MQManager mqManager)
{
   //Write to DB
    ......
   queue = mqManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQOO_OUTPUT)

   MQPutMessageOptions op = new MQPutMessageOptions();
   op.options = MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;
   queue.Put(msg, options);
   queue.Close();
}
```

When the code is like this, the connection does not participate in transaction:

```
mqManager = new MQManager("MgName","ChName","Srv(port)");
using(scope = new transaction scope)
{
   DoWork(mqManager)
   scope.complete();
}
mqManager.dossconnect();
```

When the code is like this, the connection participate in both transactions:

```
MQManager mqManager = null;
using(scope1 = new transaction scope)
{
     mqManager = new MQManager("MgName","ChName","Srv(port)");
     scope.complete()
}
using(scope = new transaction scope)
{
   DoWork(mqManager);
   scope.complete();
}
mqManager.dossconnect();
```

Why is that? 
I cannot find documentation on this subject. 
All I found was IBM documentation claiming that : "A connection might participate in several transactions, but only one transaction is active at any point of time."
But nothing about when or how to open the connection.
I would expect it to be like a DB connection, which participated only in the transaction scope it is opened in,  but here the MQmanager connection participates in any transaction, only if it was opened within a transaction scope to begin with....

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

There were couple of APAR's in this area.[APAR IT16143](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT16143) introduced changes in the MQ.NET XA Samples that were shipped with MQ.And the other APAR is IT16606. As per the XA specification, a connection can participate only in one
active transaction at a given time. The error MQRC_GLOBAL_UOW_CONFLICT
is reported if a previous transaction for a connection is still active
when the connection is used inside another unit of work. In order to
prevent this error, the application should be designed in a way that 2
transactional unit does not share the same connection handle
simultaneously.Following link talks more about transactions.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029290_.htm